# Proper way to make this data dictionary

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

I have question about what is proper way to create data dictionary.
I have never did it before but now I must.

At this moment I have to data tables:

```
public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get;set; }
    public string DeviceSerialNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string DeviceUser { get; set; }
    public int DeviceDictionaryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeviceDictionaryId")]
    public virtual DeviceDictionary DeviceDictionary {get;set;}
    public string Batch { get; set; }
}
```

and my dictionary used for creation purpose:

```
public class DeviceDictionary
{      
    public int DeviceDictionaryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DeviceManufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
}
```

And now my question.

The design I made is good or I should make some changes? I thought about spliting DeviceDictionary into 2 new tables: Manufactures and DeviceName connected with foreign key ManufacturerId.

Can anyone suggest my which way will be better for my simple solution?

Comment: mayb you should add tag what database you are using so you can attract more people from that community

Comment: @vasin1987, this question is pretty much database engine independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manufactures and DeviceName connected with foreign key ManufacturerId

Yes, you need to break this up some more. You're going to need a table for devices:

```
CREATE TABLE Device ( Id, Name, ManufacturerId )
```

(**NOTE:** the above and all following are just pseudo-code and will not compile.)

and a table for manufacturers:

```
CREATE TABLE Manufacturer ( Id, Name )
```

and since you only have one manufacturer per device you don't need a table that's many to many.

Comment: Thx. But in my situation there can't be any situation that many Manufaturers will be making same device. Database will be for making a list of things like dell e5000, samsung s2 etc

Comment: @szpic, then just move `ManufacturerId` into the `Device` table and get rid of the `DeviceDictionary` table.

Comment: So You are suggesting to keep it all in one table or what? I'm little confused now